# Dividing students into groups with added diversity rule

Tags: combinatorics

Could someone help me out for a second, please? See here's the problem:

9 greeks, 17 finns, 7 russians, 11 chinese and 8 swedish students are studying in groups. A group can consist of one or more persons. If a group has two or more persons of the same nationality, it must also have at least one person representing another nationality.
The question is: in how many different ways can the 52 students be divided into groups?

I'm thinking I’m supposed to count all possible groups, then subtract out all homogenous groups. Since we're dealing with students (who are presumably identifiable as distinct from one another), there are several groups that fit the pattern of (for example) {german, swede, russian}, and so I should be careful to count them all. But I really don’t know how to do this in the first place.

If you can show me how it’s done I will love you forever and ever as a human being. That's the best I can do.

Comment: Note that counting all possible groups is not the same as counting all the ways to distribute students into groups (ignoring the additional condition).

Comment: I removed the group-theory tag. For future reference, dividing something into groups is not a topic studied in group theory. A group is a name for a certain type of algebraic structure, unrelated to this problem.